# Multiple Images on One Position?

Tags: css

Is it possible to position multiple pictures onto one main spot on the website? For example, I'm making a website with a bunch of pictures that when you click on a picture (there's a hidden bigger picture in the middle) that pops up. When you click another picture (again, another hidden bigger picture in the same position as the first hidden picture pops up), etc., etc.

I'm having a hard time coding this because I put all the bigger pictures in one div and they just seem to slide down from one another instead of being bunched up in one spot.

Any clues?

Comment: can you show us any example for what you want to do??

Comment: @GautamJha, Sure. Give me a second to upload it to pastebin.

Comment: not clear what you want to do. use z-index maybe?

Comment: What you want to do is an image galery right? I suggest to use Javascript to set the big image url and show it.

Comment: HTML: http://pastebin.com/amhJ5Lyn
CSS: http://pastebin.com/xV4YgXDD
JS: http://pastebin.com/8LNpVj7p

Comment: Clicking on the smaller pictures: http://pastebin.com/KmVJg8nW

Comment: Should be possible if you use a `position:absolute` on all the hidden pictures

Comment: @masmrdrr, That worked. :P

Comment: @Team43 are you looking for lightbox??  http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: @GautamJha, Thanks! I didn't know this existed!

Comment: happy to help you :)